# Automatically bind buttons using jQuery. What code to put at question mark?

Tags: jquery, binding, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to automate the binding of buttons. What do I need to put down at the question marks to get an alert that is specific for button 1 and 2?

in HTML head

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (var i = 0; i < myButton.length; i++)
    {
        jQuery("#" + myButton[i].id).bind("click", function()
        {                
            alert(jQuery( --???-- ).data("text"));
        });
    }
});
```

in HTML body

```
<button type = "button" id = "btn1">btn1</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#btn1").data("text", "Howdy");
</script>

<button type = "button" id = "btn2">btn2</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#btn2").data("text", "Poo");
</script>
```

Comment: Rather than using individual calls to `.data()` after every element to set the value, you can just put `data-text="value"` in the HTML for the elements, so: `<button type="button" id="btn1" data-text="Howdy">btn1</button>`.

Comment: Nice! Much less clutter and more importantly I can get rid of the id tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of the event handler attached this way is the element the event handler is attached to, so basically you select the context `$(this)` to get the `jQuery` element of the button.

```
alert(jQuery(this).data("text"));
```

Also you can reduce your code by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function (event) {
         alert($(this).data('text'));
    }
});
```

This will attach the click handler to all buttons in your page (same as `getElementsByTagName` and then looping through each).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$(this)`:

```
alert(jQuery(this).data("text"));
```

Bear in mind that you're complicating this somewhat, through the mix of jQuery and JavaScript. You could, easily, use the following approach:

```
jQuery('button').click(function(){
    alert(jQuery(this).data('text');
});
```